# RAS popup terminal window programmatically

Tags: windows, delphi, dial-up, ras

I have a custom dialer for dial-up connections (written in delphi). It works perfectly and does a lot of great stuff... Now, i want to allow the user to configure the connection to show an after-dial terminal window as if they checked the box "Show Terminal Window" in the "Security" tab of the connection properties.

I already used RasSetEntryProperties to configure the connection, and it's ticking the box correctly... I'm also creating a RASDIALEXTENSIONS stryuucture with the option RDEOPT_PausedStates set, and passing this to the RasDial() function.

Now, I have a RasDialFunc callback created for handling the connection messages and print them in a custom way. So, when the time to show the popup dialog comes, it's only showing the text "Intereactive" meaning that the RASCS_Interactive state was reached, but NO TERMINAL WINDOW IS SHOWING UP, and the connection remains freezed, waiting for the user input of course... 
So, my problem is, how do I get the terminal window to show up?

THANKS!